# Django Uplaod and show multiple images

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, blogs

This is my Model Post where i want to uplaod multiple pictures for a specific post,so i have created foreign key from PostPicture to Post .

```py
            class Post(models.Model):
                title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
                # image = models.FileField(null = True, blank=True)
                slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
                author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
                updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
                content = models.TextField()
                created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
                status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
                #code for Thumbnail
                # image = models.ImageField(upload_to = "media", default='DEFAULT VALUE')
                image_thumbnail = ProcessedImageField(upload_to = "thumbnail",
                                                    processors = [ResizeToFill(100,50)],format = 'JPEG',options = {'quality':60},default='DEFAULT VALUE')

           class Meta:
            ordering = ['-created_on']

           def __str__(self):
            return self.title

          #code for uploading multiple images
             class PostPicture(models.Model):
               picture =models.ImageField(upload_to="blog_images", blank=True)
               postid =models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='pictures')
```

This is my template code where i am iterating through the pictures and trying to show them.

```html
          {% for i in post.pictures.all %}

              <img src =  "{{ post.pictures.url }}" height = "200", width="200"/>


          {% endfor %}
```

This is the views.py

```py
    def post_detail(request, slug):
        template_name = 'post_detail.html'
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
        new_comment = None
        # Comment posted
        if request.method == 'POST':
            comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
            if comment_form.is_valid():

                # Create Comment object but don't save to database yet
                new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
                # Assign the current post to the comment
                new_comment.post = post
                # Save the comment to the database
                new_comment.save()
        else:
            comment_form = CommentForm()

        return render(request, template_name, {'post': post,
                                               'comments': comments,
                                               'new_comment': new_comment,
                                               'comment_form': comment_form}
                                               )
```

I am using admin to add the blog post , attaching ss to have a look at the admin.[![
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEkX0.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEkX0.png)

This is the output on the UI, i am not getting the images to show up here.
[image]

I am also adding screenshot of directory :
[image]
Can anyone help me ,where i am going wrong

Comment: could you please share your settings.py file and views.py too  ?
You have to configure MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT in order to show up the images that your iterating on ?

Comment: STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media/')

Comment: @JimErginbash i have edited the question with the views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template is not right.

You're using the incorrect variable for `src` inside the for-loop:

```html
          {% for i in post.pictures.all %}

              <img src =  "{{ i.picture.url }}" height = "200", width="200"/>


          {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried using this , even though this makes more sense but the problem persist

Comment: Then do this, and open the page in the browser, and `view source`. What do you get?

Comment: I've also updated the code. Try this once and see if it works :)

Comment: i have tried using this code ,and problem is still there.

Comment: <div class>

          

             
              <img src = "" height = "200", width="200"/>

          

             
              <img src = "" height = "200", width="200"/>

          

              <img src = "" height = "200", width="200"/>

          


          </div>

this is what it shows in page source

Comment: What about the source when you put `{{ post.pictures.url }}` in your template, as in your code? I'm trying to see how/why the first picture is rendered.

Comment: this is for the thumbnail picture : <div class="post__thumbnail post__item">
          <img class="post__thumbnail__img" src="/media/thumbnail/DSC_0381.JPG">

Src is coming okay here

Comment: {{ post.pictures.url }} -> src is coming nothing here
<img src = "" height = "200", width="200"/>

and same with {{ i.pictures.url }}

Comment: can you check my views.py pleae , i think it's a reference problem

Comment: you mentioned using `{{ i.pictures.url }}` in your last comment. Please recheck that; you should be using `{{ i.picture.url }}` instead. Singular, as defined in your PostPicture Model

Comment: got it , {{ i.picture.url }} worked , as well as {{ i.picture }} is also working ! Thank you :)